# How to guarantee only one instance of a class through singletons

Tags: java, singleton

I've just learnt about the use of singletons and I'm struggling to see how they could be used to limit object instantiation to only one.

I found the following example on a tutorial website:

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton( );

private Singleton(){ }

public static Singleton getInstance( ) {
  return singleton;
   }
```

But surely each time I called the getInstance() method a new object would be created?

I'm going to try and apply the methodology to create a class that holds a hashMap and on instantiation stores within it 5 objects, so I need to understand how the principle of a 'singleton' works to prevent multiples before I can apply it.

Comment: *"But surely each time I called the getInstance() method a new object would be created?"* - no, why do you think that? `getInstance` always returns the same `Singleton` instance, *that's why it's a singleton*...

Comment: Is the `new` keyword used in `getInstance`? Why do you think a new instance is created?

Comment: BTW, overuse of singletons is a very bad habit to get into.  Understand why you need each singleton you define and why you could not have used a different mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, the reference holding the `Singleton` instance is a *static class* member.

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
```

So although, `new Singleton()` might look like creating a new instance every time, it's **not** because that *static* member gets **initialized** *only once when the class is loaded*.

The `getInstance()` *static method* then keeps returning the same reference, and hence the same `Singleton` object, throughout the life of the application.

Comment: Ah - that's perfect. Thanks for explaining it so clearly. I understand perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same instance for the application. The JVM will create the instance at the start of your program and never destroy it.

Comment: No, that's not when the instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton( );
```

is effectively executed when the class is "first referenced" -- ie, the first time that `getInstance` is called.   So it will only be executed once.

See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4), section 12.4.1.